# Identity Server4 Authentication for Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, jwt, identityserver4

I'm developing a c# windows desktop application (WinForms). I would like the application to get a JWT-token from Identity Server based on the logged in windows user. The user should not need to enter his or her credentials in the windows application. The application should use the logged in users credentials to authenticate and recieve an access token. Is this even possible?

It's not possible (of course) to get the password of a logged windows user and resend it to Identity Server. If that would be possible, the ResourceOwnerPassword flow could be used.

I've searched for an example of this but haven't found one yet. So, I'm starting 
to think that this is not possible.

The question is, is it possible in a windows desktop application to authenticate with Identity Server with the current logged in AD-user? (Without having the user enter his/her credentials)

The Identity Server will in the authentication process authenticate the user with the AD.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: which technologie your application used ? Winforms, WPF?

Comment: Updated the text with a question

Comment: If your app is supposed to be executed on a computer within a domain, you do not need jwt and Identity Server at all. Just use Windows identity everywhere. If your (target) computer is outside a domain, you can't use your windows user identity for validation (authentication) in AD. You can use ADFS and IdentityServer then, but that will be web auth, not the windows one (see how your MS VS behaves when connecting to VSTS).